# How to use regexp to identify the number of hydrogens in a chemical formula?

Tags: regex, chemistry, cheminformatics

Which expression should I use to identify the number of hydrogen atoms in a chemical formula?

For example:

C40H51N11O19 - 51 hydrogens

C2HO - 1 hydrogen

CO2 - no hydrogens (empty)

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Cheers!

Comment: You will need more than just a regular expression to do this, what language are you using ?

Comment: What result do you want for ethyl ether? "C2H50C2H5"

Comment: Whatever answer you accept, check the result for something with mercury.

Comment: Better add some sample input with mercury and maybe multiple groups containing H, like ethyl ether. Otherwise your question is unclear/too broad and will get probably ultimatly unsatisfying answers which at first seem adequate.

Comment: thanks for your observation @Yunnosch . However, I'm working only with biomolecules

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I'm using MATLAB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start using this regex :

> H\d*

H -> match literaly the H caracter
d* -> match 0 to N time a digit

see exemple and try yourself other regex at :
https://regex101.com/r/vdvH8S/2

But regex wont convert for you the result, regex only do lookup.

You need to process your result saying :

- H with a number : extract the number
- only H : 1
- no match : 0

Comment: Fails for anything with e.g. mercury or hassium.

Comment: I cover all cases in the OP

Answer (score 0):

A Regex Expression that will match H with follwowing digits would be:

```
/H(\d+)/g
```

- The 'H' is a literal charecter match to the H in the given chemical
  formula
- () declares a capture group, so you cna then grab the captured group without the H in whatever programming language you are using
- \d will match any digit along with the + modifier that matches 1 or more

There is no catch all scenarios here, you might be best using something other than a regex.

Comment: There is no catch all, I agree; but this does not even get all the cases OP gave as sample input. E.g. "C2HO"

Comment: @Yunnosch I agree completely, which is why I suggested using somethying else, however I have added this as an answer for the OP to start off with, maybe give them some guidance on regex.

Comment: Then maybe something like `([A-Z][a-z]*)(\d+*)` to take into account both  digits and element names.